# HTML Attributes not rendering in DropDownList

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have the following HTML helper in my view:

`@Html.DropDownList("Title", ViewData["Actors"] as SelectList, "---Select Actor---", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })`

But the output HTML isn't picking up the attributes correctly so the styles aren't being applied. Here is what get's output:

```
<select htmlAttributes="{ class = form-control }" id="Title" name="Title"><option value="">---Select Actor---</option>
<option value="1">Business Analyst</option>
<option value="3">Project Manager</option>
</select>
```

I suspect it's something to do with using the wrong overload, but in the peek of the definition in the intellisense it seems to correct.

Any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Title", ViewData["Actors"] as SelectList, "---Select Actor---", new { @class = "form-control"  })
```

You don't need to explicetely name property `htmlAttributes`

If you want to use the variable name then use this:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Title", ViewData["Actors"] as SelectList, "---Select Actor---", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control"  })
```

Comment: Good man, thank you! Silly typo - I copied the scaffolded code and inadvertently substituted ':' for '='. Removed the `htmlAttributes` completely and my styles are now applied and I have a handsome form again :-)

Comment: @gazrolo4 great! That always happens when copy-pasting :)